# Steam Repository installation

Tags: steam

I have been trying to install steamcmd and normal steam on bionic Ubuntu. I cant figure out how to install the missing libraries and i also want to know if there is repositories i can install. I am running armhf arch.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use the official repositories:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wget gdebi-core libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

Then, you are ready to go.

**EDIT**

- This only works for Ubuntu
- For any raspberry devices *(not 100% sure if it works or not)*, better to compile the steamCMD (check [link1](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamlug/discussions/1/627456486926897369/), [link2](https://medium.com/@jeffin.andria/raspi-steam-downloader-how-to-download-steam-games-with-steamcmd-using-raspberry-pi-3-14bb63b257d1))
- **The more you know:** Steam is only written for x86_64/x86 not ARM.

Comment: it says unable to locate packages

Comment: Check the edited post.